# Fields and $\sigma$ - fields generated by given sets.

Tags: measure-theory

Could you check if my reasoning is correct?

The field of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ (let's denote it by $\mathcal{M}$) generated  by singletons is, I think,  the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, because

$\emptyset, \mathbb{N} \in \mathcal{M}$  and

if $\{n\} \in \mathcal{M}$ , then its complement $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{n\} \in \mathcal{M}$ , and

if $\{n_1\},..., \{n_k\} \in \mathcal{M}$, then $\{n_1, ..., n_k\} \in \mathcal{M}$ and so $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{n_1, ..., n_k\} \in \mathcal{M}$.

Doesn't this mean that $\mathcal{M} = 2^{\mathbb{N}}$? 
It would mean that this field of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$  same as $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ generated by singletons.

Next, let's consider field $\mathcal{A}$ and $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by $(n, + 
\infty), n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

$(n, +\infty), (m, +\infty) \in \mathcal{A}, \ m>n \ \ \Rightarrow(n, m]\in \mathcal{A}$, because $(m, +\infty) \in \mathcal{A} \ \ \Rightarrow (-\infty, m] \in \mathcal{A}$

So here we get $\mathcal{A}=\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}, (-\infty, m], (n,m], (n, +\infty) : m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \mathcal{B}$

I would very much appreciate all your insight.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can describe the sets in $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: Will it be correct if I write
$ \mathcal{B} = \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}, (-\infty, m], (n,m], (n, +\infty), \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} (k, m] : m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ ?

Comment: @CameronBuie: Thanks for pointing out that my comment was not about the question as asked. The caffeine had not kicked in yet.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: No problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every finite subset of $\Bbb N$ will be an element of $\mathcal M,$ as will every subset of $\Bbb N$ having a finite complement. However, infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$ with infinite complements--such as $\{1,3,5,7,...\}$--will *not* be elements of $\mathcal M.$

Now, $\mathcal A$ will include all sets that are finite unions of sets of form $(-\infty,m],$ $(n,m],$ and $(n,\infty),$ where $m,n\in\Bbb Z.$ More explicitly, they will be of one of the following forms:

- $\emptyset$
- $\Bbb R$
- $(n,m],$ where $n<m$
- $(-\infty,m]$
- $(n,\infty)$
- $(n_1,m_1]\cup(n,\infty),$ where $n_1<m_1<n$
- $(-\infty,m]\cup(n_1,m_1],$ where $m<n_1<m_1$
- $(-\infty,m]\cup(n,\infty),$ where $m<n$
- $\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^k(n_j,m_j],$ where $n_1<m_1<…<n_k<m_k$
- $(-\infty,m]\cup\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^k(n_j,m_j],$ where $m<n_1<m_1<…<n_k<m_k$
- $(n,\infty)\cup\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^k(n_j,m_j],$ where $n_1<m_1<…<n_k<m_k<n$
- $(-\infty,m]\cup(n,\infty)\cup\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^k(n_j,m_j],$ where $m<n_1<m_1<…<n_k<m_k<n$

We have a similar situation with $\mathcal B,$ but it will also include sets of the following forms:

- $\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^\infty(n_j,m_j],$ where $n_1<m_1<n_2<m_2<…$
- $\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^\infty(n_j,m_j],$ where $m_1>n_1>m_2>n_2>…$
- $\bigcup\limits_{j=-\infty}^\infty(n_j,m_j],$ where $…<n_{-1}<m_{-1}<n_0<m_0<n_1<m_1<…$
- $(-\infty,m]\cup\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^\infty(n_j,m_j],$ where $m<n_1<m_1<n_2<m_2<…$
- $(n,\infty)\cup\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^\infty(n_j,m_j],$ where $n>m_1>n_1>m_2>n_2>…$

Comment: You're right. I somehow read $\sigma$-field for $\mathcal{M}$, and Mr. Nicolas apparently too.

Comment: I figured as much.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the confusion. I guess I shouldn't have used $\mathcal{M}$ to denote a field. I have one question, though. Could I say that $\mathcal{B}$ contains sets of the form $\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} (n_j, m_j]$ for all $n_j, m_j \in \mathbb{Z}$? Which case will be omitted then?

Comment: @Bilbo: That would omit no cases at all, as long as you allowed the maps $j\mapsto n_j$ and $j\mapsto m_j$ enough freedom. For example, if $n_j=m_j$ for all $j,$ then you'd simply be describing the empty set with that union. If we had $n_j<m_j$ for infinitely-many $j,$ then we could be describing any of the other cases, so long as we didn't require the maps to be increasing or bijective.

Comment: All right. Thank you a lot for you help. It all seems a lot clearer now.

Comment: @Bilbo: You're very welcome.